# Sum of a joined table

Tags: mysql

It is possible that this has been answered somewhere already but I couldn't find it. 
So would appreciate if someone could help me with this sql statement again.

This is the sql statement which I have so far:

```
SELECT * , Round( (Rate * TIME_TO_SEC( Total ) /3600 ) , 2) AS revenue
FROM (SELECT event.eventID, event.staffID, event.role, TIMEDIFF( Time, Pause ) 
AS Total,
CASE WHEN Position = 'Teamleader'
THEN (Teamleader)
WHEN Position = 'Waiter'
THEN (Waiter)
ELSE '0'
END AS Rate
FROM event, rates, eventoverview
WHERE Storno =0
AND event.eventID= eventoverview.eventID
AND event.clientid = rates.clientid
GROUP BY event.eventID, event.clientID)q1
GROUP BY q1.staffID
```

The table I am getting is now giving me a total rate per staff and event. 
But what I would like to achieve is a sum of those rates per staff. 
So basically a sum of the revenue.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon. Please include sufficient schema to cover what `*` is.  Also, please learn how to use the explicit JOIN notation instead of the implicit joins with a comma-separated list of table names in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your query in a subquery and do that in the outer query like this:

```
SELECT *,
  SUM(revenue)
FROM
(

    SELECT * , 
      Round( (Rate * TIME_TO_SEC( Total ) /3600 ) , 2) AS revenue
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT 
         event.eventID, 
         event.staffID, 
         event.role, 
         TIMEDIFF( Time, Pause ) AS Total,
         CASE WHEN Position = 'Teamleader' THEN (Teamleader)
              WHEN Position = 'Waiter'     THEN (Waiter)
              ELSE '0'
         END AS Rate
       FROM event
       INNER JOIN rates         ON event.clientid = rates.clientid
       INNER JOIN eventoverview ON event.eventID  = eventoverview.eventID
       WHERE Storno =0
       GROUP BY event.eventID, event.clientID
    )q1
    GROUP BY q1.staffID
) AS t
GROUP BY staffID;
```

**Note that:** You might get inconsistent data, due to the use of `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` `staffID` only, the columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause need to be enclosed with an aggregate function otherwise mysql will get an arbitrary value for it. This is not recommended and it it is not the standard way to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I am not getting the expected result. I want to have a total revenue per staff member and with your code the result from table t is the same as from table q1

Comment: Got it. I changed the group by for q1 and q2 to eventid.